# What's a good way to navigate back multiple pages at once while keeping the routing history in Ionic 4/Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, ionic4

I'm making an app that has multiple pages, and each one has a back button in the header. Let's say that it goes something like this: (initial pages) <-> page A <-> page B <-> page C <-> page D

On the page D, after user takes a particular action, I want to redirect back to the page A *and* forget that I went through the pages B -> C -> D. So, I shouldn't be able to return to the page D by pressing back. At the same time, I want to keep the router history of the initial pages.

I've tried doing the following on the page D:

Ionic v4 navController:

- `this.navCtrl.back()`/`this.navCtrl.pop()` - navigates back one page, erases it from history and keeps the previous history! but only works for one step back :(
- `this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/pageA');`/`this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/pageA');` - this keeps all of the history, but if I press back, I return to the page D; so, doesn't erase anything from history

Angular router:

- `this.router.navigate(["/pageA"], { replaceUrl: true });` - this is what I'm using right now, but it completely erases the history after redirect

I'm pretty sure I can keep a counter and use it in a loop to call `this.navCtrl.back()` multiple times, but it feels kinda wrong, and the user would be able to see the transitions back between all of these pages.

Is there a better way of doing this?